# Mysterious "margin-30" in responsive design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to learn pure CSS and step away from using Bootstrap for my layouts, as all I really been using it for is for the Bootstrap container. I created a bare bone project to test it out, and with pure css I have wrote my own container class:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    width: 540px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 720px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 960px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1140px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .container {
    width: 1320px;
  }
}
```

I have a simple HTML document, with a Hello World header only on the page. I have wrapped this in a div with the class container, and everything seems to be working smoothly on all screen widths, however on Chrome dev tools, in pretty much all phone display models, **a mysterious Margin -30 on the right persists.** Everything else works wonderfully as I would expect it to. What could be causing this or what am I missing?

[Screenshot of -30 right margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQCjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your padding and the default box sizing of 'content-box' (which is the size inside the padding).

When you say you want width of 100%, it needs to add a negative margin of 30px to make up for the padding because with 'content-box' you are saying "I want the width of the content to be 100% of the container".

You need to indicate the size should be based on the border (i.e. the size including the padding).

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;   << ADD THIS
}
```

Then, when you say you want width of 100%, you are saying "I want the width of the element, including the padding, to be 100% of the container".

To be honest, I find it much more intuitive for all sizing to be based on the border instead of the content.

To apply to all elements, add css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```